# How to make column data as hyperlink from another column data in dataTable (JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to make hyper link for particular column in datatables  from another column data
[image]

For example  position column should have the hyper link with data from the position column

i have tried, it has hyperlink of position column only

```
columnDefs: [             
{
                  targets:1,

                        render: function (dataSet, type, row, meta) {

                            if (type === 'display') {
                                dataSet = '<a href="http://localhost/application/org?officeid=' + encodeURIComponent(dataSet) + '">' + dataSet + '</a>';
                            }

                            return dataSet;
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the `row` property for this.  `row` represents the entire row of data so you reference it by index:

```
if (type === 'display') {
      dataSet = '<a href="http://localhost/application/org?officeid=' + row[1] + '">' + dataSet + '</a>';
   }
```

This assumes that the data in column 1 is the Office Id which I'm not sure that is present in your data, you may have to modify your query to ensure this is returned.